# Clarifying with Dirac equation

Tags: dirac-equation, mesons

The Dirac equation has a solution, $\Psi(x^\mu) = Ae^{-ip_\mu x^\mu / \hbar} u(p^\mu)$ and   $\Psi(x^\mu) = Ae^{+ip_\mu x^\mu / \hbar} \nu(p^\mu)$, where $u(p^\mu)$ corresponds to the particle solution and $\nu(p^\mu)$ corresponds to the anti-particle solution.

From the wiki article about meson there is a line there that says, " according to the Dirac equation, a quark and an antiquark have opposite intrinsic parities ".

Now my question , is this because that the exponent in the particle solution is negative while the anti-particle solution is positive? Just want to clarify.

Now if this is not the case can someone give an insight given this four set of solutions,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the opposite intrinsic parities of anti-particles can be seen from the signs in the exponents.